# Values of $n$ and $r$ for which $ n \choose r$ is defined

Tags: combinatorics

I started learning about binomial theorem where my teacher told me that for binomial coefficient
$ n \choose r$ to be defined -

$n$ $\in$ $ \mathbb{N}$ ,

$r$ $\in$ $ \mathbb{W}$,

$n$ $\ge$ $r$

but out of some curiosity I looked whether  $0 \choose 0$ is defined or not and I found out from this site only that it is defined , therefore

$n$ must  $\in$ $ \mathbb{W}$?

Comment: What is $\mathbb W$?

Comment: set of whole numbers

Comment: First, it must be clarified what you mean by the binomial coefficient.  If you are very explicitly using the binomial coefficient defined in elementary-set-theory and in combinatorics where $\binom{n}{r}$ counts the number of $r$-element subsets of an $n$-element set then $\binom{0}{0}$ is indeed defined and is equal to $1$.  Similarly, $\binom{n}{r}$ is *defined* (*and not undefined*) and just happens to *equal zero* in those scenarios where there are no $r$-element subsets of an $n$-element set, either because no such sets exist since $r$ or $n$ are not natural numbers, or because $r>n$ etc

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient#Generalization_to_negative_integers_n

Comment: Next, it should be pointed out that there does exist the *generalized* binomial coefficient which is used more in algebraic settings rather than purely combinatorial settings, where $\binom{n}{r} = \dfrac{n\frac{r}{~}}{r!}$ where we still require $r$ to be natural but we relax the requirement on $n$, allowing for such things as $\binom{-3}{2}=\dfrac{(-3)(-4)}{2!}=6$ or $\binom{\pi}{5}=\frac{\pi(\pi-1)(\pi-2)(\pi-3)(\pi-4)}{5!}$

Comment: The set of whole numbers is denoted $\mathbb{N}$ or $\mathbb{Z}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically ${n \choose r}$ is defined as the quotient of products:

$$\dfrac{ \overbrace{n\cdot (n-1)\cdot(n-2) \cdots}^{\text {r terms} }}
{\underbrace{r\cdot (r-1)\cdot(n-2) \cdots \cdot 1}_{\text {r terms} }}$$

So ${4/3 \choose 4}$ would be

$$\dfrac{ (4/3)(1/3)(-2/3)(-5/3)}{(4)(3)(2)(1)} = \frac{5}{243}$$

With the convention that $\Pi \emptyset = 1$, so ${k \choose 0} = 1$.